# Is there a way to not limit vertex painting to visible geometry?

Tags: mesh, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

Is there a setting for vertex painting which allows you to paint on geometry that is visually obscured from the view by geometry in front of it?  (I am looking for something similar to the *limit selection to visible* toggle in edit mode.)

Here is a picture that illustrates what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I have a simple object consisting of two planes.  I painted across the entire object from the view shown on the left.  However, as seen on the right, you can see that it did not paint the part of the back plane covered by the front plane.  Is there a way to paint "through" geometry like this?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct answer, but you could try the following:

- Enter Edit Mode, turn off the limit (marked in red), and use the brush to select vertices you want to paint:
  [image]
- Then enter Vertex paint Mode, and turn on the face selection mask:
  [image]
- It doesn't matter where you click with your brush, because the paint is limited to the selected faces
  [image]

Results are (at the front)
[image]

and (at the back)
[image]